# Compile/Link unused Functions/Procedures in Delphi

Tags: delphi, compiler-construction, linker, delphi-7

I would like to "provide" several functions/procedures or even vars in my application without ever using them in my own code. Does the compiler automatically ignore unused vars and functions or is it the linker? How can I change that? I already tried to uncheck `CodeGeneration ---> Optimization` but with no luck.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "provide", but not including unused code and vars in a compiled app is a basic optimization that every compiler does (or should do).

Comment: How can you actually do that without calling the function or reading/writing a var, etc.

Comment: Without references the linker will strip out the code but if it did't how would YOU refer to that code?

Comment: Note that you just need to reference code, say by taking its address, to prevent it from being stripped out - you need not call it.

Comment: You just need to take the address of it, @name

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If something in your program refers to the object then the linker cannot remove it. So you can take advantage of this like this:

```
procedure StopLinkerRemoval(P: Pointer);
begin
end;
```

Then in your initialization section you can write this:

```
StopLinkerRemoval(@MyVar);
StopLinkerRemoval(@MyFunction);
```

All you need to do is refer to the object. You don't need to call the function, or read/write the variable, just take its address.

Comment: This would be easiest. Thank you very much. I'm gonna put the StopLinkerRemoval procedure to my library and call it whenever I need it :)

Comment: @Ben Just for curiosity, but when would that be?

Comment: I need it so other applications can call CreateRemoteThread on my process.

Comment: How are those other applications going to discover the thread function? In my experience, any means to make the function discoverable will lead to the function being referenced and therefore not removed by the linker.

Answer (score 4):

To have "unused" or not referenced `procedures`/`functions` and also `private` and `protected` `methods` compiled in your application you should build a package and put the `dcu` files into your library path.

`public` and `published` `methods` are compiled even without being referenced in your application.

Comment: +1 this is a really awesome discovery! Very handy for lots of code!

Comment: But it's more complicated than that. Objects defined in the implementation section only may be stripped. And private members may be stripped. Only things accessible outside the package need be kept alive.

Answer (score 1):

The linker is the one that ignores the unused variables. I am not sure if it does the same with procedures and functions, however. You cannot alter this change.

Comment: +1 Thank you for your answer. Now I know it is the linker settings, that I may have to change.